# Navbar deconnexion button hover on two lines not wanted

Tags: html, css

I would like a deconnexion button to appear when hovering on the menu "Bonjour Toi".

But it's showed on 2 lines instead of 1.

As "Toi" can be changed according to user name, when the name is longer the menu deconnexion is correctly showed on 1 line.

Here is what i have now:

[image]

Here is my html code:

```css
.nav-top {
  background-color: #475162;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.nav-top nav .logo{
  float:left;
}

.nav-top nav .logo{
  margin-left:20px;
}
.nav-top nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-top nav ul {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav-top nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-top nav li a  {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Raleway, arial;
}

.nav-top ul li a.active {
  border: solid 1px #FF307E;
}

.nav-top ul  li a:hover:not(.active)  {
  border: solid 1px #FF307E;
}

/* BUTTON DECONNEXION */
.nav-top nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.nav-top nav ul li ul{
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-height:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.nav-top nav ul li:hover ul{
  max-height:15em;
}

.nav-top nav ul li ul a{
  padding:8px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-top nav ul li ul a img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

 .nav-top nav ul li:hover li a{
   background-color: #FF307E;
   color:white;
   text-transform:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-top">
  <nav>
    <div>
      <div>
        <a routerLink='./'><img class="logo" src="./assets/img/logo.png" height="70px"></a>      
      
      <ul>
        <li><a>BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a>SUPPORT</a></li>
        <li ><a class="active ">Bonjour {{nameUserConnected}}</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a (click)="confirmLogout()"><img src="./assets/img/logout.png" width="17px" />&nbsp;Déconnexion</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>  
</div>
```

How can I get the deconnexion + icon on the same line ?

Comment: The example you have provided shows the icon and 'deconnexion' on the same line - can you inspect your site with dev tools and provide more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here. The `ul` that is positioned absolute will have the width of the element it's relative to. Which is the `li` containing `Bonjour Toi` . That's why when it's longer, it will fit. If the text is smaller , the ul won't fit. You also set `overflow:hidden` on it , you need to remove that

I changed a bit your code ( the image i've set it like a background-image and `padding-left` of `a` is equal to the width of image, change it as you like )

All new/changed code is at the top of the CSS styles

see below

```css
.nav-top nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-height: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.nav-top nav ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico') no-repeat scroll left center #FF307E;
}

.nav-top nav ul li ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.nav-top nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
}

.nav-top {
  background-color: #475162;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-top nav .logo {
  float: left;
}

.nav-top nav .logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.nav-top nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-top nav ul {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.nav-top nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav-top nav li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Raleway, arial;
}

.nav-top ul li a.active {
  border: solid 1px #FF307E;
}

.nav-top ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
  border: solid 1px #FF307E;
}


/* BUTTON DECONNEXION */

.nav-top nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-top nav ul li:hover ul {
  max-height: 15em;
}

.nav-top nav ul li ul a {
  padding: 8px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-top nav ul li ul a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-top nav ul li:hover li a {
  background-color: #FF307E;
  color: white;
  text-transform: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-top">
  <nav>
    <div>
      <a routerLink='./'><img class="logo" src="./assets/img/logo.png" height="70px"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a>SUPPORT</a></li>
        <li><a class="active ">Bonjour Toi</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a (click)="confirmLogout()">Déconnexion</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much you are a god